# Networkx drawing axes with frameon = False and axes = False

Tags: python, networkx

I am drawing and saving my figure with the following:

```
nx.draw_networkx(dG,pos,labels,font_size=12,node_size=0,edge_color='y',width = 0.5)
plt.savefig('new.eps', format='eps', dpi=200,frameon=False, axes = False,bbox_inches='tight')
```

But it's saving it with axes.

Yet, when I put

```
plt.axis('off')
```

before the two lines above, it eliminates the axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the call signature of `savefig` (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)):

```
savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
    orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
    transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
    frameon=None)
```

The `frameon` keyword argument just tells it whether there is a colored background.  The `axes=False` option that you sent it is completely ignored because `axes` isn't a keyword argument for `savefig`.

So without your `plt.axis('off')` there's nothing you've done to tell it not to put any axes in there.

If I were to code this, I would do it as

```
nx.draw_networkx(dG,pos,labels,font_size=12,node_size=0,edge_color='y',width = 0.5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('new.eps', dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The `format = 'eps'` is unnecessary.  If you don't set the `format` keyword, it figures out what format to save in from the extension in the filename you give.

---

(to see how it ignores keywords that it isn't expecting:

```
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.savefig('test.pdf', garbldeygook = False)
```

runs with no error even though `garbldeygook` isn't a keyword for `savefig`)